# sending command into CMD in c#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, process

I wanna simple send this string into cmd command line

```
string arg= "ffmpeg.exe - i " + txtInput.Text + " " + txtOutput.Text + "";
```

I tried this

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", arg);
```

But nothing happen, so how can I execute this command in cmd without showing the cmd to the user?

Comment: Add a /C before ffmpeg as argument to cmd.exe

Comment: Why dont you process.start the ffmpeg.exe directly setting `-i whatever` as args?

Comment: Yeah I saw it in a few questions on Stackoverflow but I don't wanna hide at this point, first I wanna see if the command is executed. Which I can't right now. Still don't know why but my command does not reach to cmd.exe It's just opening cmd cant pass my string into cmd

Answer (score 3):

why not starting `ffmpeg.exe` directly instead of `cmd.exe`

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\foo\ffmpeg.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i " + txtInput.Text + " -o " + txtOutput.Text;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I had no idea I could do that, its my first time I'm dealing with processes. The ffmpeg.exe is added as system variable on my computer I could use it on my computer but wouldn't work on someone else's computer I guess right? I'll try the solution now

Comment: update---
When I try to open the exe its just closing itself so I have to open it from cmd and type the exe to cmd :/

Answer (score 0):

First thank you for the idea @fubo
this code worked for me

```
 string arg2 = " -i \"E:\\Test Folder\\Sample.mp4\" \"E:\\Test Folder\\sample.avi";

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\\ffmpeg.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = arg2;
            p.Start();
```

now I can move on and keep digging ffmpeg deeper since I know how to execute it now :)

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.exe` simply launches a new command prompt instance.  This is similar to using `powershell.exe`.  When you are already in `cmd` and run `cmd` there's not a difference.  Try swapping between `powershell.exe` and `cmd.exe` and it's noticeable.

Run `cmd /?` to display a list of arguments you can run against cmd.  One of which is `cmd /C`:

> /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates

You asked "how can I execute this command in cmd without showing the cmd to the user?".  Well for that you also need `ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true`.  For example:

```
    void Main()
    {
        string arg = $"/C ffmpeg.exe - i ${txtInput.Text}  ${txtOutput.Text}";
        launch(arg);
    }


static void launch(string arg)
{
    Process proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd",
            Arguments = arg,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true//This is important
        }
    };

    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();//May need to wait for the process to exit too
}
```